What exactly happens when you typedef a function pointer b/c my test code works but I don't think it should?
I am learning C and C++.  I wrote a program in C++ and I am writing the same program in C.  I want to use structs in C to mimic the classes I wrote in C++.  To this end, I wrote test code that (1) creates a typedef to a function pointer, (2) a struct with the typedef as a member, and (3) assigns the member to a compatible function.
#include <stdio.h>

// comment 1 -- see next line
typedef int (*type_def_func_ptr) (int, int);

int result(int x, int y){
    int temp_result = x + y;
    return temp_result;
}

struct TEST_STRUCT {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    type_def_func_ptr tdfp;
};

int main(){
    struct TEST_STRUCT MyStruct;
    MyStruct.day = 28;
    MyStruct.month = 9;
    MyStruct.year = 2024;
        // comment 2 -- see next line
    MyStruct.tdfp = result; 
    int result1 = MyStruct.tdfp(28, 9);
    printf("Result1 is %d\n", result1);
}

The code works.  I don't understand, however, why the code works as written without (1) result() being *result() (comment 1) or (2) without MyStruct.tdfp = result being = &result (comment 2).  The code still works with (2) being &result or *result, which leads me to believe that the compiler is interpreting what I wrote instead of blindly compiling what I wrote.

In C functions decay to pointers to themselves, similarly to the way that arrays decay to pointers to their first element. With that said, please note that C and C++ are two very different languages. I recommend you learn only one at a time, and when learning the second basically forget everything you learned from the first.


int result1 = MyStruct.tdfp(28, 9); and int result1 = (*MyStruct.tdfp)(28, 9); do the same thing.

MyStruct.tdfp = result; and MyStruct.tdfp = &result; also do the same thing.


These convenience "shortcuts" do the same thing as in C++ (in which you only need & to take the address of functions if they are member functions).


Functions when used in expressions (without parameter list) decay to pointers.
It does not matter if you use & or not.
when function pointer is used with parameters it derefences the function pointer and call the referenced function.

I do not like function pointers typedefs. I prefer function types to have consistent pointer semantics:
typedef int type_def_func (int, int);

int result(int x, int y){
    int temp_result = x + y;
    return temp_result;
}

struct TEST_STRUCT {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    type_def_func *tdfp;
};

void foo(type_def_func *tdfp);

//etc etc


Re “when function pointer is used with parameters it derefences the function pointer and call the referenced function”: It is the other way around. C 2018 6.5.2.2 1 constrains the main operand of a function call expression to be a pointer to a function. If a function (properly, a function designator) is passed, it is automatically converted to a pointer. Similarly “Functions when used in expressions (without parameters) decay to pointers” should not exclude use of a function “without parameters”. A function designator is only not converted when it is the operand of unary & or of sizeof.

@EricPostpischil without parameters means without even an empty parameter list.

The point is the exclusion is inappropriate. The sentence says when a function is used without an argument list (not a parameter list), it is indeed converted to a pointer. But when a function is used with an argument list, it is still converted to a pointer. The exceptions to the automatic conversion are for use with unary & and sizeof. There is no exception for use with a parameter/argument list.
